# Is it possible to limit the input file size in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m having trouble finding a way to limit the input file size in FFmpeg.

I’ve got a site that welcomes uploaded videos of 60 seconds in length, but need a safeguard in case someone tries to upload a 50GB file and paralyses my server’s CPU and storage.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to limit the size *before* passing the file to FFmpeg?

Comment: @TRiG is right. You should limit the filesize with a server-side scripting language. Otherwise, you can simply pipe the file through an utility like `head` (I think it has a flag for bytes).

Comment: Yes, you guys are totally right. I'm a bit of a novice and don't know what that scripting language would look like, but I'll keep researching. Thanks guys!